# can we store logger msg in arraylist

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
   logger.info("[{}],- STATUS :: {}, n , n+1); // sending some values in logger.
}
```

I want to store all the logger msg in some arraylist and use at the end . how to store logger message in arraylist

Comment: what logger library is this using?

Comment: Why not make an ArrayList of Strings and add the logged message to it every time you call logger info?

Comment: slf4j logger @OldProgrammer

Comment: suppose there are multiple cases for which i am printing message on console  but i need to track the steps whatever is executed and send it to the client via mail . so how will I do it here as I do not want to make another function writing some hard coded text . instead is there any way that i can store the logger message itself . at the end of thread i can mail to client whatever the steps haven completed

Answer (score 0):

The info method of any logger library converts the message object passed as parameter to a string by invoking the appropriate ObjectRenderer.
Hence even if you pass arraylist as a parameter, it will convert the object into some String value(basically hash value) and store that value which is not of any use.